# Laravel sort collection by multi fields

Tags: laravel, sorting, collections

I stucked with a collection sorting in laravel based on different situations.

For simplicity here is an example collection:

```
1;
 pmt: 1
 thm: 1
 customerFriendly: false
2;
 pmt: 1
 thm: 1
 customerFriendly: true
3;
 pmt: 2
 thm: 4
 customerFriendly: true
```

I need to sort this collection first based on the pmt value. Lowest first.
If there are same pmt values than I need a second sorting based on the thm value.
After that if there is maybe a same thm than I need to sort it again by the customer boolean field.

So based on the above example the final sorted list should be 2,1,3

As far as I get I can sort the list first by pmt and if same pmt-s found by thm, but I cant sort it by customerFriendly.

Here is my code:

```
$pmtDuplicated = $this->checkDuplicates($transformedLoans, 'pmt');
                if ($pmtDuplicated) { //If we found same pmt-s sort by thm also
                    $secondSort = $transformedLoans->sortBy(function ($item) {
                        return $item->pmt . '-' . $item->thm;
                    })->values();

                    $thmDuplicatesInSecondSort = $this->checkDuplicates($secondSort, 'thm'); //Check again for same thm

                    if ($thmDuplicatesInSecondSort) { //If we found same thm sort by customerFriendly also
                        return $secondSort->sortBy('customerFriendly')->values();
                    } else {
                        return $secondSort;
                    }
                } else {
                    return $transformedLoans->sortBy('pmt')->values();
                }
```

Someone maybe can help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and I leave it here if for someone is a help later.

Instead of this section:

```
if ($thmDuplicatesInSecondSort) { //If we found same thm sort by customerFriendly also
                        return $secondSort->sortBy('customerFriendly')->values();
                    }
```

I needed to use this:

```
if ($thmDuplicatesInSecondSort) { //Ha van THM alapján is egyezés akkor fogyasztóbarát alapján is rendezzen
                        return $secondSort->sortBy(function ($item) {
                            return $item->customerFriendly === false ? 1 : 0;
                        })->values();
```

}